# Performance of UIImageView and CoreAnimation

Tags: xcode, ipad, animation, uiimageview, caanimation

I'm working on very simple game. Everything is working. 
I've only question about performance and memory. 
I'm moving bird from left to right. The bird waves his wings in 3 positions.

What's better solution regarding speed, performance, memory:

1. animate uiview changing 3 complete pictures with bird and wing in differnet positions
2. create bird background and animate single wing image using CALayer animation

Thanks for replies:)
Alex

UPDATE: and what about more complex animations ??

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only 3 images (as described in your question), you can go with simpler `UIView` animation approach.

But, using `CoreAnimation` will give you better performance.

When using 3 different images, instead of changing pictures and animating views, you can use animation property of `UIImageView` itself.

Say `image01.png`, `image02.png` and `image03.png` are your images.

```
    UIImageView *animationImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    NSArray *animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image01.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image02.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image03.png"],
                                        nil];
    [animationImgView setAnimationImages:animationImages];   // Add images to imageView for animation.
    [animationImgView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];           // Repeat forever.
    [animationImgView startAnimating];                     // ImageView starts animating.
```

Then animate position of `UIImageView`